# Prove that if $(x+y)$ is even, then $(x-y)$ is even, for integers.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am completely stuck on how to prove this. I need to prove it multiple ways too (directly, contrapositive and by contradiction). My problem is that I can't figure out how to isolate $x$ and $y$ in order to be able to show the difference between $x+y$ and $x-y$.

The only thing I can think of is first to prove that if $x$ and $y$ are both even, then $x+y$ is even. But then, if they are both odd, $x+y$ is also even. So I'm not sure this is the right way to go, unless I do multiple proofs, one for when $x$ and $y$ are both odd and one for when $x$ and $y$ are both even. Not sure this is the right way to go. Would it be sort of a proof by cases then? Like, prove that if x+y is even then $x-y$ is even, when $x$ and $y$ are both even and $x$ and $y$ are both odd?

The other solution I thought of would be to assume if $x+y$ is even, then it is equal to $2k$. And then somehow show that $2k$ is the addition of $2$ integers... I tried to show that $x = 2k - y$ but that doesn't show me anything, and when I tried to do the same for $y$ and substitute, I end up with $x = 2k - 2k - x$ and I get $x = -x$ which obviously doesn't make sense.

I'm pretty frustrated with this problem... I am comfortable with the different proof methods but I am stuck on how to express this properly. Any advice on how to approach it?

Thanks

Answer (score 16):

**Hint**: $(x-y) = (x+y) - 2y$. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 8):

**BRIC-Fan**’s solution is probably the slickest way to proceed, but you can also pursue your idea of considering what evenness of $x+y$ tells you about $x$ and $y$. Specifically, it tells you that $x$ and $y$ have the same parity: both are odd, or both are even. Now consider those cases separately: show that the difference of two integers of the same parity is always even. In algebraic terms this amounts to showing that for any integers $m$ and $n$, $2m-2n$ and $(2m+1)-(2n+1)$ are both even: the former is a general expression for the difference of two even integers, and the latter is a general expression for the difference of two odd integers.

Your idea of writing $x+y$ as $2k$ is also workable: then $y=2k-x$, so

$$x-y=x-(2k-x)=2x-2k=\ldots$$

Comment: Thank you, I see it now, after your last example.

Comment: @waffledave: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2):

for integers $x$ and $y$, 
$$
(-1)^{x+y} = (-1)^x(-1)^y =(-1)^x (\frac1{-1})^y=(-1)^x(-1)^{-y} = (-1)^{x-y}
$$

Comment: This doesn't seem complete without at least mentioning (and preferably proving) that $\;(-1)^x = 1\;$ iff $\;x\;$ is even.  But it is a nice way of phrasing the parity argument.